# Running Hapi Lab experiments using distinct server instances

Tags: hapi.js

I'm updating a library to work with the latest Hapi libraries, including Lab.  With the old version of Lab, I was able to run two `experiment`s, each with their own `Hapi.server` instance, and both using port `3000`.  The new version of Lab, however, either finishes too quickly, or run asynchronously, causing a "port in use" error on the second experiment.

```js
var lab = exports.lab = Lab.script();
var routes = [{...}, {...}, {...}];

lab.before(async () => { ... });

lab.experiment('experiments', () => {

    lab.experiment('experiment 1', () => {

        var server;

        lab.before(() => {
          server = Hapi.server({ port: 3000 });
          return server.start();
        });

        lab.test('test 1.1', async () => {
            return server.register(Plugin)
            .then(() => server.route(routes))
            .catch((error) => console.log(error));
        });

        lab.experiment('experiment 1.1', () => {
            lab.test('test 1.1.1', async () => {
                const response = await server.inject({...});
                Code.expect(response.result)...;
            });

            lab.test('test 1.1.2', async () => {
                const response = await server.inject({...});
                Code.expect(response.result)...;
            });
        });
        
    });

    lab.experiment('experiment 2', () => {

        var server;

        lab.before(() => {
          server = Hapi.server({ port: 3000 });  
          return server.start();
        });

        lab.test('test 1.1', async () => {
            return server.register([{...}, {...}])
            .then(() => server.route(routes))
            .catch((error) => console.log(error));
        });

        lab.experiment('experiment 2.1', () => {
            lab.test('test 2.1.1', async () => {
                const response = await server.inject({...});
                Code.expect(response.result)...;
            });
            lab.test('test 2.1.2', async () => {
                const response = await server.inject({...});
                Code.expect(response.statusCode)...;
            });
        });
    });
});
```

The second experiment fails:

```
listen EADDRINUSE: address already in use 0.0.0.0:3000
      at Server.setupListenHandle [as _listen2] (net.js:1318:16)
      at listenInCluster (net.js:1366:12)
      at doListen (net.js:1503:7)
      at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:81:21)

There were 1 test script error(s).
```

Changing the port to `3001` solves the problem, but I'd like to know what changed with Lab, and what changes can I make so the same port can be used for both server instances.

Comment: Seeing the same issue